# Android service stops when I exit from application

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have an application with a service. Service is started by app in the main activity on create method. My problem occurs  when I exit from application: service stops and sometimes restarts immediately, sometimes restarts lately. I tested in version 4.1.2 and version 2.3.6.  service does not again in version 2.3.6. Is my approach wrong? Between the stop and restart times, the call that must blocked can come. Is there any way to not stop the service when app is exited?
Note: I cannot use a remote service.

i added startForeground to service but the same problem. when i exit application the service stopped and not restart version 2.3.3 even i see notification.But phoneStateListener takes null value
How can i ensure when i exit application, the service does not stop

```
 //application main metod
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {              
//.....

    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyPhoneStateListener.class));
}




 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
 {
    setCallListener();    
    setNoti();
    return START_STICKY;
 }

 private void setCallListener()
 {
        try
        {
            if (phoneStateListener==null)
            {

              phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
              telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                 telephonymanager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }
```

private void setNoti()
    {

```
    Notification notification= new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,  getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, main,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.blockstate)[Sabitler.ShieldState].toString(), pendingIntent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    startForeground(123456, notification);  
}
```

i change the where setting callstatelistener from service to broadcast as Dhawal Sodha advised but in this case blocking unwanted call get slow. i think on broadcast TelephonyManager initializes every calling. Broadcast code below. When i use service,
when main activity is exited service stopped in version 2.3.3. Any idea ? Broadcast or service ? How can make broadcast faster? every calling  variables and object initialize again in broadcast.

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    MyCustomStateListener myCustomStateListener;
    TelephonyManager telephonymanager;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        try
        {
            //Log.e("receiver1",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            myCustomStateListener = new MyCustomStateListener(context,telephonymanager);
            telephonymanager.listen(myCustomStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            //Log.e("receiver2",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            telephonymanager.listen(myCustomStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(context,"setCallListener:"+ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: you want to block number??? then just use this code in Broadcast receive.. instead of start service..

Comment: When you say "service stops", you mean that its onDestroy() is called after finishing your activity? Also, when you say "exit application", do you mean just finishing the activity?

Comment: yes finishing main activity with System.exit(0);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-closed

Comment: i have added an answer on this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46539560/2414767)

Answer (score 7):

Are you starting the Service with `startService`?
If so, when you end your activity, the service is not bound to anything and can be stopped by the system.

If you want to run a background Service regardless of your activities, use `startForeground` and provide a constant notification.

See the Service reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

**UPDATE**

Finishing your app with `System.exit(0)`?
Of course your service stops, that kills your process.
You should never exit an application like that - just `finish()` your activity.

Comment: i change the where setting callstatelistener from service to broadcast as Dhawal Sodha advised but in this case blocking unwanted call get slow. i think

Answer (score 7):

Add this code in your onStartCommand() method

```
  showToast("onStart");

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotStickyActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

  Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
              .setContentTitle("Pratikk")
              .setContentText("Subject")
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
              .build();

  startForeground(1234, noti);     

  return Service.START_STICKY;
```

It will not stops your service.

Comment: When kill the application this service is stopping also the notification dismissed from the notification bar