# android start service from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

How to start service from broadcast receiver when application is killed and service stay alive.
My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ImageUploader.class);
    if (wifi != null && wifi.isAvailable()) {
        context.startService(intent1);
        Toast.makeText(context, "start service execute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(mobile != null && mobile.isAvailable()) {
        context.startService(intent1);
    }
}
```

}

When application is started, all work fine. But when i killed app, i see only toast, service was sleeping. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

From the answer of "SirKnigget" in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276738/android-service-stops-when-i-exit-from-application)

It may be change from

> startService(...)

to

> startForeground (...)

And also careful about quit the application by

> System.exit(0)

The services will stop. So use

> finish()

to exit from the application.

You can find additional information from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Hope this help to solve your problem.