# Check internet connection in background

Tags: android

I need to check for internet connection in background....
i am saving some data in my database and whenever i get internet connection,
it should upload the data on my server...
i need a background service which will check for internet connection continuously even if i close my App,
i tried few methods but they all work only if i open my app...
Currently i am checking the internet connection like this

```
/checking internet connection

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

        //we are connected to a network
        connected = true;

    }
    else
       //not connected to internet
        connected = false;

    if(connected) {
        //getting teacher data if INTERNET_STATE is true(if will be still true if connected to a wifi or network without internet)
        getOfflineSubjectData();
        getTeacherData();
    }
    else{
        getOfflineSubjectData();
        Toast.makeText(teacher_homePage.this,"no internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**NOTE**
I don't want a method which will not work after i close my app...
Just like whatsapp when we close the app,We still get text messages

Comment: you have to stop your service from being killed when app is closed.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: restart your service in your service's onDestroy() method

Comment: post your service code or broadcast receiver you can use instead

Comment: Go through this Tutorial, a very nice explanation. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Comment: @AjayPandya right now i am only checking the internet on my main thread...

Comment: Start sticky service and and check your internet connection in _onStartCommand()_ method.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's too late to answer your question but still, this is a perfectly working solution.

We can easily do it by using a Service and a Broadcast Receiver simultaneously to get the output as you wish. This will work always i.e when app is running, app is minimized or when app is even removed from minimized apps.

1. Manifest Code :

   ```
   <application
   ...
   <service android:name=".MyService" />
   </application>
   ```
2. MyService.java

   ```
   import android.app.Notification;
   import android.app.NotificationManager;
   import android.app.PendingIntent;
   import android.app.Service;
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.IntentFilter;
   import android.os.IBinder;
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class MyService extends Service {

   static final String CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";
   NotificationManager manager ;

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
       BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               String action = intent.getAction();
               if (CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                   //check internet connection
                   if (!ConnectionHelper.isConnectedOrConnecting(context)) {
                       if (context != null) {
                           boolean show = false;
                           if (ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs == -1) {//first time
                               show = true;
                               ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                           } else {
                               if (System.currentTimeMillis() - ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs > 1000) {
                                   show = true;
                                   ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                               }
                           }

                           if (show && ConnectionHelper.isOnline) {
                               ConnectionHelper.isOnline = false;
                               Log.i("NETWORK123","Connection lost");
                               //manager.cancelAll();
                           }
                       }
                   } else {
                       Log.i("NETWORK123","Connected");
                       showNotifications("APP" , "It is working");
                       // Perform your actions here
                       ConnectionHelper.isOnline = true;
                   }
               }
           }
       };
       registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
       return START_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   }
   ```
3. ConnectionHelper.java

   ```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
   import android.net.NetworkInfo;

   public class ConnectionHelper {

   public static long lastNoConnectionTs = -1;
   public static boolean isOnline = true;

   public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
   }

   public static boolean isConnectedOrConnecting(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)         context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   return activeNetwork != null &&
   activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
   }

   }
   ```
4. Your Activity Code

   ```
   startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
   ```

Comment: Does this not work when the app is the killed state ?

Answer (score 5):

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CheckConnectivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    if(isConnected){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
 }
```

Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.connect.broadcast"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <receiver android:exported="false"
          android:name=".CheckConnectivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: main activity does nothing here we get connection status in broadcast receiver (same as whatsapp fetch messages)

Comment: thats what i dont want...i want a service to run in background which will check for internet ...it would be really helpfull...just like whatsapp...if we close it...we still receive messages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276738/android-service-stops-when-i-exit-from-application      this will make your service immortal

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am stuck in the same thing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276738/android-service-stops-when-i-exit-from-application @ShuchiSheth

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some better way, but I've implemented this as a STICK_SERVICE as @Rahul suggested, and for avoiding killing the service I forced a fixed notification in status bar. I know this probably is not a good practice, however the client has asked to show "App is running..." in the status bar, so it's ok.

**SyncService.class**

```
public class SyncService extends IntentService {

    private static int FOREGROUND_ID = 1338;
    public Boolean isServiceRunning = false;
    Integer delay;
    private NotificationManager mgr;

    public SyncService() {
        super("SyncService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(@Nullable Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        performSync();
        startSyncThread();
        mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = buildForeground();
        startForeground(1, builder.build());
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public Boolean isWifiConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        return mWifi.isConnected();
    }

    public void startSyncThread() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        delay = 1000;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                performSync();
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    public void performSync() {
        if (isWifiConnected()) {
            Log.i("SyncService:", "Wifi connected, start syncing...");
            Sync sync = new Sync(this);
            sync.postPhotos();
            sync.postEvents();
            sync.getEvents();
            delay = 60000;
        } else {
            Log.i("SyncService:", "Wifi IS NOT connected, ABORT syncing...");
            delay = 1000;
        }
        Log.i("SyncService:", delay + "");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        WakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }


    private NotificationCompat.Builder buildForeground() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        b.setContentTitle("Prime Share is running")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync_noanim)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        return (b);

    }

}
```

And then in my first activity onCreate I call this:

```
context = this;
startSyncIntent = new Intent(this, SyncService.class);
startService(startSyncIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

use this method anywhere

```
if (!isNetworkAvailable(this)) {

   } else {}
```

Answer (score -2):

Code check internet access by using timer, I have made a service for that
First time I have posted on stack.... so sorry in advance because i am not able to post it in good format

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    long notify_interval = 1000;
    public static String str_receiver = "pravin.service.receiver";
    Intent intent;
    DatabaseHandler dh=new DatabaseHandler(this);
    public CheckInternet(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetInternetStatus(), 5, notify_interval);
        intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
    }
    private class TimerTaskToGetInternetStatus extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    icConnected();
                }
            });

        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startid)
    {


    }
    public boolean icConnected()
    {
        Log.d("Called " , "INTERNET");
        ConnectivityManager connec =
                (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Check for network connections
        if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {
                Log.d("INTERNET","TRUE");
                dh.getIssues();
                return true;
            // if connected with internet

            //makeText(this, " Connected ", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (
                connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||
                        connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {
                Log.d("INTERNET","FALSE");
                return false;
            //makeText(this, " Not Connected ", LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```